# select specific columns in csv/df with varying headers python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, header

I have several CSV files that contain variants of the same information.
I want to extract columns from each of them based on keywords. However, the header of each file does not necessarily start in the 1st row, making it challenging to identify a static variable for ´skiprows=´.

Here are some examples of the CSVs

CSV1

```
Here are the instructions that you should follow.
Follow them closely, OK, to define the Type and Place.

Type    Number  Place   Exists
cat 2   home    yes
dog 2   field   yes
fish    3   sea yes
```

CSV2

```
   .



I know have this type of information.
This is not easy to define when the location and style are the same.

Animal Style    Quantity    Location    Exists
horse   3   field   yes
lion    2   safari  no
tiger 3 jungle  yes


CSV3

Number  Local   Species
2   home    rabbit
3   tank    turtle
3   sea shark
```

The ´pandas´ approach I would have followed if the ´CSVs´ all had an easily identifiable header is the following:

```
colFilters = ['number','local','species','style','quantity','location','type','number','place']
df = read_CSV(CSV1,skip_blanks_rows=True)
df.columns = map(str.lower, df.columns)
df = df.filter(regex='|'.join(colFiltersFilters),axis=1) 
df.head
```

I could have skipped the rows that do not contain key words, but there are key words that at times appear in the 'instructions' that are placed in different places above the header.

Is there a way that ´pandas´ can use particular information to identify the header columns? Is there a better approach to this problema than simply relying on the header information and/or number of headers?

Comment: Note that the `df` tag is for the Unix command by that name and has nothing to do with dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

So basically your strings are stored in Column 1? What if you drop all NULL values when you read in your data? After that you can rename your column headers with your first row.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv(r'CSV1',header=None)
df=df.dropna()
df=df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0])
df=df.drop(df.index[[0]])
df.head(10)
```

If you have missing values in any other column then I would either delete all rows that contain a '.'. Or delete all rows that have more than 2 missing values

Comment: the data is different number columns and does not necessarily start in first row. Meaning that in case cases there is irrelavent content that comes before the header columns.